# How to pass a Promise.all return to another function Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set a few variables from Firebase and then pass those into a `anotherfunction`.  Currently, the `Promise.all` is properly setting `foo` and `bar`, however, I can't tell if `foo` and `bar` are being passed into `then`, and also Firebase is not properly scoped.

The `Promise.all` block is based on a tutorial found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgZIb6Uwpjc&t=305s

```
exports.someFunction = functions.database.ref(`/data`).onWrite(event => {
  const condition = event.data.val()
  if (condition) {
    // Get the data at this location only once, returns a promise, to ensure retrieval of foo and bar
    const foo = event.data.adminRef.child('foo').once('value')
    const bar = event.data.adminRef.child('bar').once('value')

    return Promise.all([foo, bar]).then(results => {
      const foo = results[0].val()
      const bar = results[1].val()
      // Properly sets foo and bar
      // As far as I can tell foo and bar are not passed into 'then'
    }).then([foo, bar] => {
      return someModule.anotherFunction({
        "foo": foo,
        "bar": bar
      })
    })
  } else {
    console.log('Fail');
  }
});
```

How can I pass `foo` and `bar` into `anotherFunction` and set the response of that function to Firebase?

Comment: your first .then returns nothing, so your second .then wont receive foo or bar ... try `return [foo, bar]`

Comment: actually, the line `}).then([foo, bar] => {` is irrelevant **and incorrect syntaxt** in your example - remove that line and celebrate the fact that foo and bar are defined

Comment: `.then([foo, bar] => {})` should be `.then(([foo, bar]) => {})`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, you addressed both issues at your Answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's where you've gone wrong - see the comments in the code

```
return Promise.all([foo, bar]).then(results => {
  const foo = results[0].val()
  const bar = results[1].val()
  // you dont' return anything so, the following .then gets undefined argument
}).then([foo, bar] => {
  //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ invalid syntax, you need .then(([foo, bar]) =>
  return someModule.anotherFunction({
    "foo": foo,
    "bar": bar
  })
```

To simplify your code, just remove `}).then([foo, bar] => {` altogether!!

```
return Promise.all([foo, bar])
.then(results => {
    const foo = results[0].val()
    const bar = results[1].val()
    return someModule.anotherFunction({
        "foo": foo,
        "bar": bar
    }))
.then ...
```

But, if there's more to the actual code than you show, you can do

```
return Promise.all([foo, bar])
.then(results => results.map(result => result.val()))
.then(([foo, bar]) => someModule.anotherFunction({
    "foo": foo,
    "bar": bar
}))
.then ...
```

or

```
return Promise.all([foo, bar])
.then(([foo, bar]) => ([foo.val(), bar.val()]))
.then(([foo, bar]) => someModule.anotherFunction({
    "foo": foo,
    "bar": bar
}))
.then ...
```

Comment: This simplified code solution seems to work up until an error is thrown for Firebase not being defined.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - firebase not being defined is more to do with your original code which doesn't seem to refer to firebase at all

Comment: I will clean up this submission to be more promise-specific, and resubmit the Firebase problem separately with (hopefully) cleaner code.

Comment: Here is the link if you would like to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43960390/how-to-scope-firebase-in-nested-promise-cloud-functions-firebase

Answer (score 4):

in the first `then`
add

```
return Promise.resolve([foo,bar]);
```

or (as per @Jaromanda X)

```
return [foo, bar];
```

Comment: or just `return [foo, bar];` - because it's in a .then, you know