# How to scope Firebase in nested promise Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set a few variables from Firebase and then pass those into a anotherfunction. Currently, the Promise.all is properly setting foo and bar, but an error is being thrown during the `.then`, so the response isn't getting set in Firebase.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions'),
  admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.someFunc = functions.database.ref(`/data`).onWrite(event => {
  const condition = event.data.val()
  if (condition) {
    // Get the data at this location only once, returns a promise, to ensure retrieval of foo and bar
    const foo = event.data.adminRef.child('foo').once('value')
    const bar = event.data.adminRef.child('bar').once('value')

    return Promise.all([foo, bar]).then(results => {
      const foo = results[0].val()
      const bar = results[1].val()

      return someModule.anotherFunction({
        "foo": foo,
        "bar": bar
      }).then(response => {
        // Get an error thrown that Firebase is not defined
        let updates = {}
        updates['/data'] = response
        return firebase.database().ref().update(updates)
      })
    })
  } else {
    console.log('Fail')
  }
});
```

The error logged into the console is as follows:

```
ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
    at someModule.anotherFunction.then.response 
(/user_code/index.js:100:16)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
```

How can `return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);` be scoped to set the response from `anotherFunction`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [include the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import_the_required_modules_and_initialize), typically called `admin`.

As shown and explained in the [getting started documentation for functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import_the_required_modules_and_initialize):

> ### Import the required modules and initialize
>
> For this sample, your project must import the Cloud Functions and Admin SDK modules using Node require statements. Add lines like the following to your `index.js` file:
>
> ```
> const functions = require('firebase-functions');
>
> const admin = require('firebase-admin');
> admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
> ```
>
> These lines load the `firebase-functions` and `firebase-admin` modules, and initialize an `admin` app instance from which Realtime Database changes can be made.

You then use it like this:

```
return admin.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Also see this [complete example in the `functions-samples` repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/d14e397c8bcd79cb72f18a579492ae7a37dcba61/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/index.js).

Comment: Frank, thank you for your thoughtful and expedient reply.  I did base this function on the Firebase ```functions-samples``` posted on GitHub.  I should have been more verbose with the example and included the constants and initialization in the question.  I have now updated the code with the initialization and the error that was logged to the console.

Comment: You're still calling `firebase.database().ref().update(updates)`. As my answer says, that should be `admin.database().ref().update(updates)`.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I missed that.